# json multidimensional array from Alfresco

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array, alfresco

I am trying to consume an Alfresco api which returns information about some documents stored under a specific Alfresco directory.

My problem is that on the Json that i am getting , when I am trying to return for example the value from cmis:name I am getting an underfined error.

I managed to reach until the "properties" level but i am not able to go any further. Could you please advise me ?

Thank you in advance.

```
 success: function (json) {

          $.each(json, function () {
              $.each(this, function (key, value) {
                  console.log(value.object.properties);
              });
              });
      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the correct way to access the last level and get the value :

```
success: function (json) {

          $.each(json, function () {
              $.each(this, function (key, value) {
                  console.log(value.object.properties['cmis:name'].value);
              });
              });
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

did you query like this:

http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/example/cmis/query?format=json&q=select%20cmis:name,cmis:objectId%20from%20cmis:document%20where%20cmis:name%20=%27testwhitepaper%27

then you will get:

```
{"query": "select cmis:name,cmis:objectId from cmis:document where cmis:name ='testwhitepaper'",
"results": [
{"name":"testwhitepaper",
 "id":"workspace://SpacesStore/9a007b6a-261a-4d6d-9e34-ded4430ba1ab;1.0"
},
{"name":"testwhitepaper",
 "id":"workspace://SpacesStore/3356ff7d-4172-4bd5-a826-adfa541e6ad2;1.0"
}
]
}
```

Comment: no, its a typical ajax request, my url is : url: 'http://alfresco.companyname.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/root/sites/ops-it/documentLibrary/Documentation/Intranet' and i want to get the list with the document names in that folder